# how to get two list concanate in one in python

Tags: python, list

hello I would like to get two list in one

I have one list of name and one other of number in string i would like to say :

```
for i,j in map(None,[school,phonenumber]):
    phrase = "{} : {}".format(i,j)
    complete.append(phrase)
```

school and phonenumber are the list but I don't understand how to do for get the index of each line

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

f = open('phone.csv')
phonenumber = list(csv.reader(f))


f = open("school2.csv", "r")
school = list(csv.reader(f))




complete = []


   for i,j in map(None,[school,phonenumber]):
      phrase = "{} : {}".format(i,j)
      complete.append(phrase)

print(complete)
```

I have tried that and I don't know where it's wrong

I would like just school : phonenumber ....

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
You need [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
 for i,j in zip(school,phonenumber):
      phrase = "{} : {}".format(i,j)
      complete.append(phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is what you are looking for

```
for i,j in zip(school,phonenumber):
```

Comment: and I don't know why but when I un my code it's sort at first all the school and after the number